# how to seperate corn at root

Tags: roots

I have a question about corn, im a first time grower and I made the mistake of putting my baby corn together in one pot thinking only for a moment. well life happened and they had to sit for a week in this one pot and have grown pretty good. but I now need to put them in the ground. I'm just scared the roots are bunched up together,  How would one separate the roots without damage?